# Send OnClick command to all Dynamic TColorButtons on TabSheet

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm working on a PingTool and I've got a TabSheet of dynamically created buttons(anywhere from 1-150 based on user input) and I would like to be able to pass the OnClick command to all buttons on the given TabSheet. My individual button clicks successfully run my ping code, but I get a EStackOverflow message when clicking my PingAll button. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code Excerpt below:

Code used for button creation:

```
begin
  For x := 0 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count -1 Do
  Begin
  If CheckListBox1.Checked[x]=true then
    begin
      GLCount := (GLCount +1);
      theIP :=(CheckListBox1.Items.Strings[x]);
        if GLcount < 10 then begin
          B := TColorButton.Create(Self);
          B.Name:= ('BTN'+intToStr(GLCount+1));
          B.Caption := theIP;
          B.Parent := TabSheet2;
          B.Height := 25;
          B.Width := 97;
          B.Left := 0 + GLCount * 96;
          B.Top := 8;
          B.BackColor := clBtnFace;
          B.ForeColor := clBtnText;
          B.OnClick := CustomButtonClick;
         end;
```

CustomButtonClick Code:

```
Procedure TForm1.CustomButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GlobalIP:=TColorButton(Sender).caption;
  IdIcmpClient1.Host := GlobalIP;
  IdIcmpClient1.ReceiveTimeout := 500;
  IdIcmpClient1.Ping();

case IdIcmpClient1.ReplyStatus.ReplyStatusType of
  rsEcho:
    TColorButton(Sender).BackColor := clGreen;
  rsTimeOut:
    TColorButton(Sender).BackColor := clRed;
end;
end;
```

PingAll Code(not working):

```
procedure TForm1.PingAllClick(Sender: TObject);
var
i: integer;

begin
  For i := 0 to TabSheet2.ControlCount -1 do
    if TabSheet2.Controls[i] is TColorButton then
    begin
    TColorButton(Sender).Click;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you have a IdAntiFreeze or similar component in your form?

Comment: I do not. Unfortunately I'm still pretty green with Delphi and not 100% sure what IdAntiFreeze does. The problem I'm experiencing seems to be related to the handling of the PingAll ButtonClick rather than the actual ping being performed as my "CustomButtonClick" procedure works as expected when clicking any of the dynamically created buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling recurcive the method PingAllClick... look that you call TColorButton(Sender).Click instead

```
....
Control := tabSheet2.Controls[i]
if Control  is TColorButton then
  TColorButton(Control ).Click()
....
```

Comment: Awesome. Looks like that was my issue. Changed my bottom line and it works great now.

    TColorButton(TabSheet2.Controls[i]).Click;

Comment: Nice catch, I missed that! :)